# Is JVM handle an Exception when we write

Tags: java, jvm

Does the JVM handle an `Exception` when the `main()` method is declared like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will compile, no warning or error message was given by compiler.

Comment: Then the JVM *has* to handle the exception somehow.  The OS won't...it doesn't know Java exceptions even exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the exception is handled by the JVM by the [default exception handler](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=229).

You can change this behavior at the thread, thread group, or VM level by use of one of:

- `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionhandler()`
- `ThreadGroup.uncaughtException()`
- `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`

As a simple example:

```
public class Program {    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {        
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                System.err.println("Uhhh something broke.");    
            }
        });

        int a = 5 / 0; 
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
Uhhh something broke.
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it prints the stacktrace, unless you are invoking it yourself. In that case, you handle it.